# Expand the %system% directories to full path

Tags: c#, path

In my program, I am getting the path of the default website in IIS through the following code:

```
ServerManager manager = new ServerManager();
string path = manager.Sites["Default Web Site"].Applications["/"].VirtualDirectories["/"].PhysicalPath;
```

`path = %ystemdrive%\inetpub\wwwroot`

Path.GetFullPath doesn't look like appropriate thing for this. How do I get the full path from the above, which actually is `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(path);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables()`

Also see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx).